# AWS S3 trouble getting Object Attributes from server while get Object works fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with CloudFront in front of it. Server side I want to implement a feature in which I get the attributes from the S3 bucket without using CloudFront.

For some reason, getting the whole object just works without using CloudFront from the server, while getting the attributes gives a Access Denied error.

My bucket is configured like so:

```
Access
Bucket and objects not public

Block all public access
 On

{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAttributes"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XX/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::ACCOUNTID:distribution/DISTRIBUTION"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowServerAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAttributes"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XX/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

For reference, this code works:

```
let result = self
    .aws_s3_client
    .get_object()
    .bucket(&*common::properties::AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME)
    .key(&path)
    .send()
    .await;
```

and this fails:

```
let result = self
    .aws_s3_client
    .get_object_attributes()
    .bucket(&*common::properties::AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME)
    .key(&path)
    .send()
    .await;
```

Comment: Is versioning enabled on the bucket?

Comment: What does CloudFront have to do with this? Do both requests work via CloudFront but one doesn't work directly?